# c# Filestream can not handle big binaryfile

Tags: c#, position, filestream

File size is over 6GB,  however while ReadFileSteam_ORI2 's position being over 3,960,000,000
test4 buffer was filled with zero's. (real file data are not zeros. )  Maybe reading process failed internally, I think. Why this issue appears?
under 3,960,000,000 position, no error and all process works well.

```c#
long now_pos2 = 0;
FileStream ReadFileStream_ORI2 = new FileStream(
  d_ori.FileName,
  FileMode.Open,
  FileAccess.Read,
  FileShare.Read
);

byte[] test4 = new byte[10000000];

for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
{ 

  if (i==396) {; }

  ReadFileStream_ORI2.Seek(now_pos2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  ReadFileStream_ORI2.Read(test4, 0, 10000000);
  now_pos2 += 10000000;
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep seeking to `now_pos2`?

Comment: I've tested your code with .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.7.2 and can confirm that it works correctly, and doesn't exhibit the "filled with zeroes" behaviour that you're seeing.

Comment: This is the test code for checking issues, In my program,  now_pos2  is randomly moved back and forth by value

Comment: In your real code, are you actually reading from a file? If you're not, you can't assume that asking to read 10,000,000 bytes will actually result in that many bytes being read. You should check the result of `Read` to see how many bytes were actually read.

Comment: It is tested for over 6 GB size file? ..   I've tested code  .NET framework  4.6.1   So I'll change  build environment like you.

Comment: I tested a 5 GB file of random data. I also just tested 15 GB and no issues there either. [This is the modified code that I used for my most recent tests](https://pastebin.com/8PqgnHkG).

Comment: Is related with unsafe function?  I ran this code in unsafe function.

Comment: Llama, I runned your code, but reading process itself well, however, acturally real read data is all zero , After 3,960,000,000 position of my file (6GB)

Comment: I suspect that's related to your file then. I was using test files from [here](https://fastest.fish/test-files). Are you sure your file doesn't contain 10 MB of "all zero" data?